# excel VBA : operating with dates from spread sheet into a while/do

Tags: vba, date, loops, excel

I'm trying to write a macro that inserts duplicate rows (as many as specified in a column), and at the same time changes the date ahead for each duplicate. 
Something like

```
BEFORE                                     AFTER
20/01/2013   2                             20/01/2013   2       
28/02/2013   0                             21/01/2013   2
15/03/2013   1                             22/01/2013   2
                                           28/02/2013   0
                                           15/03/2013   1
                                           16/03/2013   1
```

the duplicate part works just great, but it's the date changing that is giving me a headache. I tried with

```
Cells(x,y).Value = Cells(x,y).Value + 1
```

but it does not work with date

Dateadd hasn't brought me anywhere either...
here comes the code...thank you to anybody who will help me

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
' ola
'

Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim z As Integer


    i = 2
    x = Application.InputBox("Number of Rows", "Number of Rows", Type:=1)
    k = Application.InputBox("Column", "Choose 1 for A, 2 for B, 5 for E...", Type:=1)


Do
    y = Cells(i, k).Value
    If y = 0 Then
    i = (i + 1)
    Cells(i, k).Activate
    Else
            z = 0
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
            Range(ActiveCell.Offset(y), ActiveCell.Offset(1)).EntireRow.Insert
            Do
                i = i + 1
                z = z + 1
                Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value + z
            Loop While z < (y + 1)
            Cells(i, k).Activate
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If

Loop While i < x


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try creating a `Date` type variable from the content of the cell ie.

if `Range("A1")` is `20/01/2013` then

```
dim myDate as Date
myDate = CDate(Range("A1"))
```

`Cdate()` converts whatever is in the cell into a `Date` type. So instead of relying on the compiler to select the data type of the cell content you are explicitly telling the compiler to treat contents as Date.

now you can add to date using `DateAdd()` function

```
myDate = DateAdd("d", 1, myDate)
```

and write back to a different cell

```
Range("A2") = myDate
```

a one-liner could possibly be

```
Cells(x,y).Offset(1,0) = DateAdd("d", 1, Cdate(Cells(x,y)))
```

Probably an easier solution would be to say

```
Cells(x, y) = CDate(Cells(x,y)) + 1
```

but now, at least you understand *why* and *how*

Comment: thanks for the quick answer
range("A1")  is not possible for me since I need to use symbols (I am putting them into the while/do) , that is why I'm using cells and not range...other than that I suspect that the thing is not working because my cells are not formatted right...I've tried to select them and change format to date, but I'm not sure it's working
I'll try what you said, using cells, and get back in a sec

Comment: @user3115524 sorry so what is the probleM?

Comment: ok, just tried this

Do

                i = i + 1

                z = z + 1

                dTheDate = DateAdd("d", z, CDate(Cells(i, 4)))

                Cells(i, 4).Value = dTheDate

            Loop While z < (y + 1)

and it completely disfigured my excel file (I had a backup :) )
but for the first time it didn't give me errors, it's a start

Comment: @user3115524 if you don't mind uploading the file to a free hosting site and giving me the link I can probably work this out work you if you cant get it to work. Although since you didnt get an error its just the matter of adjusting the right coordinates